# Spring Boot Jpa PostegreSql Deploy Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, tomcat

I've a problem deploying a Spring Boot app on remote Tomcat 9.0.54 server.

My app use jdbc postgresql driver and in local work great (on local tomcat too), but on remote server make a strange error.
The dialect and driver changes and I cannot understand anymore, maybe you can help.

This is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Project</name>
    <description>Project backend service</description>
    <properties>
        <app.title>Project</app.title>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
        <jsch.version>0.1.55</jsch.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <binding.version>0.2.0</binding.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.54</tomcat.version>
        <app.profiles>development,production</app.profiles>
        <sonar.exclusions>
            pom.xml,**/*.md
        </sonar.exclusions>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            **/configuration/*,
            **/controller/*,
            **/dto/**/*,anymore
            **/entity/*,
            **/mapper/*,
            **/repository/*,
            **/service/*,
            **/utility/*
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>${jsch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>development</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>production</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>Project</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The app properties:

```
#Datasource
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.10.18:5432/project
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

#Jpa
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

anymore
If it deployed in Eclipse or local Tomcat (9.0.54) consoles returns:

Eclipse

```
23:27:18.728 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1ff641e2

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2022-11-28 23:27:19.411  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.project.ProjectApplication       : Starting ProjectApplication using Java 1.8.0_352 on devel with PID 65301 (/home/jack/docs/GitHub/project/target/classes started by jack in /home/jack/docs/GitHub/project)
2022-11-28 23:27:19.413 DEBUG 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.project.ProjectApplication        : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
2022-11-28 23:27:19.414  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.project.ProjectApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "development"
2022-11-28 23:27:22.415  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-11-28 23:27:22.489  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2022-11-28 23:27:22.723  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-28 23:27:23.709  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-11-28 23:27:24.681  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-11-28 23:27:26.920  INFO 65301 --- [  restartedMain] o.e.project.ProjectApplication       : Started DeployTedApplication in 8.173 seconds (JVM running for 9.196)
```

Local Tomcat

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2022-11-28 22:49:31.028  INFO 60600 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.3 using Java 11.0.17 on devel with PID 60600 (/home/jack/downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/webapps/Project/WEB-INF/classes started by jack in /home/jack/downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/bin)
2022-11-28 22:49:31.031 DEBUG 60600 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
2022-11-28 22:49:31.032  INFO 60600 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : The following 1 profile is active: "development"
2022-11-28 22:49:33.243  INFO 60600 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-11-28 22:49:33.316  INFO 60600 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2022-11-28 22:49:33.532  INFO 60600 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-28 22:49:34.473  INFO 60600 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-11-28 22:49:35.238  INFO 60600 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-11-28 22:49:37.240  INFO 60600 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : Started ServletInitializer in 6.796 seconds (JVM running for 9.944)
```

And on remote server:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2022-11-28 22:46:03.741  INFO 9009 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.3 using Java 11.0.11 on naosweb with PID 9009 (/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/webapps/DeployTED/WEB-INF/classes started by tomcat in /home/tomcat)
2022-11-28 22:46:03.745 DEBUG 9009 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
2022-11-28 22:46:03.746  INFO 9009 --- [           main] org.example.project.ServletInitializer  : The following 1 profile is active: "development"
2022-11-28 22:46:05.806  INFO 9009 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-11-28 22:46:05.889  INFO 9009 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2022-11-28 22:46:06.124  INFO 9009 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-28 22:46:06.525  INFO 9009 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-11-28 22:46:06.776  WARN 9009 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2022-11-28 22:46:06.779  WARN 9009 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
2022-11-28 22:46:06.919 ERROR 9009 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect does not support sequences
2022-11-28 22:46:06.968 ERROR 9009 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect does not support sequences
....
28-Nov-2022 22:47:08.223 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [Project] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
28-Nov-2022 22:47:08.223 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Project] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler.LoggedExceptionHandlerThreadLocal] (value [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler$LoggedExceptionHandlerThreadLocal@281d7c2d]) and a value of type [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler] (value [org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler@bcb4c2e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: spring boot seems to pick up properties/classes from "remote tomcat" (environment) Possibly: overriden properties (OS, System, "external application.properties", ...), or maybe even "just": a mysql driver in "shared" tomcat-lib (i.e. classpath) (see: the advantage of containerized development!? ..your java versions differ ;(

Comment: I've installed new tomcat instance, the same that run locally. Same problem. I'll view in the environment config.